# Read passwords for Fastfile from a file - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, fastlane, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have an android project using **KotlinDSL**.

I create APK and submit it to **AppCenter** and **Play Store**. At the moment, I am putting some keys and passwords for these environments in **Fastfile** as follows.

```
lane :build_test_app do
       gradle(
             task: "assemble",
             build_type: "Release",
             flavor: "Dev",
             print_command: false,
             properties: {
                 "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "/Users/user/Desktop/appjks",
                 "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "asd123,
                 "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "asd123456",
                 "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "asd1234",
             }
         )
    end
```

-> Or as below to build apk

```
private_lane :upload_apk_to_appcenter do
        appcenter_upload(
               api_token: "0123.....",             
               owner_name: "MyCompany",
               owner_type: "user",
               app_os: 'Android',
               app_platform: 'Java',
               app_name: "MyApp",
               file: lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH],
            
        )
    end
```

-> Slack url as below

```
before_all do  
    ENV["SLACK_URL"] = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/123asd......."
end
```

I think all these passwords should not be in this file. I want to read these from a file that won't be added to git. For example **local.properties**.

How can I do this or how can I do it best?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.read()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_read.asp) for a local file. Create a `password.txt` file in your project folder along with a [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). You can read the password from there like this:

```
puts(password: File.read("../password.txt"))
```

Comment: How do I access the keys in the password? I would be very happy if you could share a document etc. explaining this.

Comment: I hope this blog will help: https://blog.devgenius.io/fastlane-json-d5e03f36ebcd

Comment: Also read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614480/10659482